Proving that the set of non-negative half-integers satisfies Peano's axioms
I postulate that the following set $\{0,0.5,1,1.5,...\}$ represents the natural numbers. Of course, intuitively, this isn't true. But let me try to show this using Peano's axioms. I'll first define the successor operation to be the following:
$$\sigma(n) = n+0.5$$
Now, axiom 1 is satisfied: $0\in S$. It is also the case that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\sigma(n)\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, axiom 2 is satisfied. It's also true that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \sigma(n)\neq0$. Thus, axiom 3 is satisfied. Even the axiom 4 - injectivity axiom - is true: $\sigma(n)=\sigma(m)\implies n=m$.
Now, onto axiom 5. I've seen two kinds of formulations so far:

If $P(n)$ is some property such that $P(0)$ is true, and whenever $P(n)$ is true $P(\sigma(n))$ is true, then $P(n)$ is true for every number
For every $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ with the property that $0\in S$ and $s\in S\implies \sigma(s) \in S$, $S = \mathbb{N}$

Here are my questions:

How are the two formulations of the axiom equivalent?
How do you show that the set obeys/disobeys axiom 5 using each of the formulations?
If the set obeys axiom 5, isn't that a problem since the set is intuitively not what we mean when we refer to natural numbers?


As pointed out in this answer, we could in some sense consider the fifth axiom to be a converse of the conjunction of the first and second axioms.

I'll answer your third question first. One interesting thing about the Peano Axioms is that there is not just one structure that they describe. Rather, they describe a family of structures that are the same in very specific ways.
To be more precise, suppose that we had two sets $S$ and $T,$ as well as two functions $f$ and $g$ whose domains are $S$ and $T$ (respectively).
Suppose further that the following hold:

$\exists b\in S$
$\exists m\in T$
$\forall x\in S,f(x)\in S$
$\forall x\in T,g(x)\in T$
$\forall x\in S,f(x)\neq b$
$\forall x\in T,g(x)\neq m$
$\forall x\in S,\forall y\in S, \bigl[f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y\bigr]$
$\forall x\in T,\forall y\in T, \bigl[g(x)=g(y) \implies x=y\bigr]$
$\forall A\subseteq S,\Bigl(\bigl[b\in A\wedge\forall x\in A,f(x)\in A\bigr]\implies A=S\Bigr)$
$\forall A\subseteq T,\Bigl(\bigl[m\in A\wedge\forall x\in A,g(x)\in A\bigr]\implies A=T\Bigr)$

That is, we're supposing that the triples $\langle S,f,b\rangle$ and $\langle T,g,m\rangle$ satisfy the Peano axioms. Then structurally speaking, these triples are effectively interchangeable in that, if there is a statement $P(S,f,b)$ that is provable as a consequence of the Peano axioms, then $P(T,g,m)$ is likewise provable as a consequence of the Peano axioms, and vice versa. We might call any such triple a "Peano structure."
Some examples of Peano structures (of varying degrees of intuitiveness) include:

$\langle\Bbb N,\sigma,0\rangle,$ where $\Bbb N$ is the set of non-negative integers and $\sigma:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is given by $\sigma(n)=n+1$
$\langle\Bbb N_+,\sigma\!\restriction_{\Bbb N_+},1\rangle,$ where $\Bbb N_+$ is the set of positive integers
$\langle\Bbb N',\sigma',0\rangle,$ where $\Bbb N'$ is the set of halves of the usual natural numbers from your example and $\sigma'$ is your adjusted successor function
Given any non-zero real number $r$ and any non-zero real number $s$ such that $\lvert s\rvert\neq 1,$ we can define $\Bbb N^*:=\left\{s^n\cdot r\mid n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ and define $\rho:\Bbb N^*\to\Bbb N^*$ by $\rho(x)=s\cdot x,$ and we'll find that $\langle\Bbb N^*,\rho,r\rangle$ ia a Peano structure.
Given literally any countably infinite set $X,$ there is a Peano structure $\langle X,f,e\rangle.$ To see why, take any bijection $g:X\to\Bbb N,$ let $e=g^{-1}(0),$ and define $f:X\to X$ by $f(x):=\left(g^{-1}\circ\sigma\circ g\right)(x).$

Thus, there is a proper class of examples of Peano structures that are distinct, but still effectively the same. When structures are interchangeable in this way under some context, we say they are isomorphic.

As far as the formulae you mention, the second is what I would say is properly a Peano axiom. The first is a logical consequence thereof but it is about statements about the Peano structure, rather than being about the Peano structure, itself. To prove it from the fifth Peano axiom, here is a big hint: for any statement $P(n)$ quantified over $n\in\Bbb N$ (whichever version of $\Bbb N$ we're considering), $S:=\bigl\{n\in\Bbb N\mid P(n)\bigr\}$ is a well-defined subset of $\Bbb N.$
On the other hand, given any subset $S$ of $\Bbb N$ (whichever version of $\Bbb N$ we're considering), $P(n)$ given by $n\in S$ is a well-defined statement. In this way, we can prove that the second formulation is implied by the first, too!

I will leave it to you to show that your set satisfies the fifth Peano axiom.

Thanks for rhe rigorous answer. The isomorphic perspective helps clarify a lot. I suppose proving that the set abides by the Peano's axioms is easy using the second formulation of the fifth axiom. 0 is in the set. Also, by definition of the successor, it is obviously the case that succ(n) is in the set. Would that line of reasoning be valid?

I'm glad it was helpful! I just added another example, by the way. In terms of your line of reasoning, I'm not sure you're on the right track. You're trying to prove that if we have any subset $A$ of $\Bbb N^$ such that $0\in A$ and such that $\sigma(x)\in A$ whenever $x\in A,$ then $A=\Bbb N^.$ It suffices to show that $\Bbb N^\subseteq A.$ Moreover, the natural isomorphisms between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N^$ given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ or $g(y)=2y$ should help you to prove it!

I suppose the method you propose allows me to generalize the proof for any multiplier, not just 0.5. But I don't see the problem with the rather straightforward line of reasoning I provided. Could you please point out the specific issue with it?

Good call on the multiplier! Your line of reasoning seems to be that axioms 1 and 2 hold, and therefore, so does axiom 5. However, that need not be the case. Consider instead the structure $\langle\Bbb N',\sigma,0\rangle,$ where $\sigma$ is the unadjusted successor function. Then this structure satisfies Peano axioms 1 and 2 (as well as 3 and 4), but not 5, because $\Bbb N\subseteq \Bbb N',$ $0\in\Bbb N,$ and $\sigma(n)\in\Bbb N$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,$ but $\Bbb N'\not\subseteq\Bbb N.$

Also, I just noticed that in this comment, I got confused! I meant $\Bbb N'$ instead of $\Bbb N^*$ each time in that comment, and $\sigma'$ instead of $\sigma$ each time in that comment. Sorry if that caused any confusion!
